# Unable to install specific GNOME Shell extension

Tags: gnome, software-installation, 15.10, gnome-shell-extension

I am trying to install [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) GNOME Shell extension as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/702133/364819), however even though I press the switch to make it `On` rather than `Off` and I click `Install` on the little dialog that I get, when I refresh the page it is `Off` again and there is no sign of it in `gnome-tweak-tool`.

I have tried installing other extensions the same way and there is no problem, so why am I unable to install this one? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Wilf: Firefox 42.

Comment: @Wilf: But it worked for the other extensions so I don't see why it wouldn't do for this one.

Comment: For every extension it has a file saying what versions its supports. In this case it doesn't support 3.18. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works here *on 3.16* (which I guessed you had originally as by default 15.10 should have 3.16 (see [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2014-September/002278.html) for a reason))... I don't think it supports 3.18 from the extension page (When you have a 'unsupported' shell version for that extension, it won't give any informative errors, which is STUPID).

As a workaround (may not work), you can download the source of the extension from [here](https://bitbucket.org/emasab/shelltile/downloads) (Click '[Download repository](https://bitbucket.org/emasab/shelltile/get/9d2f872fd905.zip)'), then execute `build.sh` in the extracted source's directory (`cd` into from termial, or use 'Open in terminal'). After that, you can extract the `ShellTile@emasab.it.zip` file to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`.

Place it so the metadata file is at: `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ShellTile@emasab.it/metadata.json`. You need to ensure the metadata file contains your gnome shell version - example:

```
{
  "_generated": "Generated by SweetTooth, do not edit", 
  "description": "A tiling window extension for GNOME Shell. Just move a window over another one, holding down the Control key, and you'll see the magic! Grouped windows minimize, resize, raise and change workspace together. Maximize a window to remove it from the group.", 
  "gettext-domain": "shelltile", 
  "name": "ShellTile", 
  "settings-schema": "org.gnome.shell.extensions.shelltile", 
  "shell-version": [
    "3.6", 
    "3.8", 
    "3.10", 
    "3.12", 
    "3.14", 
    "3.16",
    "3.18"
  ], 
  "url": "https://bitbucket.org/emasab/shelltile", 
  "uuid": "ShellTile@emasab.it", 
  "version": 30
}
```

Here are various checks/workarounds if it supports your version (it doesn't in this case but help others):

- Reload the browser page.
- Ensure the Gnome Shell Integration plugin is enabled (check `about:plugins` in Firefox)
- Check whether the extension is enabled with Gnome Tweak Tool or [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/)
- If you have not previously installed the extension it should show something like:
  [image]
  If it is installed and working you there will be a preferences icon
- It'll be installed if this folder exists:

  ```
  ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ShellTile@emasab.it
  ```
- Give up, report a bug:

  https://bitbucket.org/emasab/shelltile/issues?status=new&status=open