# How do I make a second window snap to the opposite side of the screen?

Tags: gnome, window, window-manager, snap-windows

I'm coming from Windows 10, although I've started (and accepted) the way Ubuntu works, their are still a few things that I love about Windows 10, the feature in question here is the way If I snap one windows to the extreme right side of display it takes up the right half portion of the display (which is also similar in ubuntu) but another app in background takes the left half of display and doesn't need to manually do that.

[image: Screenshot]

In this picture, if I snap the Browser windows to the right, Nautilus window wouldn't affect by the action, But I want it (nautilus window) to snap to left

Details

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Gnome flavour

**Update**

result of the `fillscreen.py` script

[image: 1st result]

in first try *fillscreen* notification came (I couldn't capture that) and it moved the 2nd window (window in the right) in a box, and 1st window wasn't affected at all.

[image: 2nd result]

in second try, this offset was present, but it did work (and it mostly works)

Comment: Hi Sumeet, if you run this one https://askubuntu.com/a/709787/72216 with the arguments 2 1 : `python3 /path/to/script.py 2 1` it will do exactly what you want. Please let me know if you manage or not.

Comment: @JacobVlijm that did solve my problem, but i was looking something like Windows 10 implementation, where other window just snaps to the opposite side

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice. Unfortunately, Unity does not offer settings like that, so we can only do it with trickery & deceit :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm i'm using gnome, does Kde have that feature? or a better implementation than gnome or unity?

Comment: Ah, sure my bad, no, it does not exist in any Ubuntu flavor as far as I know.

Comment: It would be scriptable thoug, but it might be too demanding. I might do an attempt... will let you know if it is a usable option.

Comment: @JacobVlijm everybody just wants to hear that :)

Comment: Hi Sumeet, see this https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1xm8xe3e6hw6yj/fill_screen.avi?dl=0 would that be an option?

Comment: @JacobVlijm that looks amazing! will it work in Gnome? how can I implement that?

Comment: SumeetDeshmukh yeah, it will work on pretty much all windowmanagers that work with both xdotool and wmctrl. I asked to reopen your question :) After reopening, I will post probably tonight, need to write a polished story :)

Comment: Hi Sumeet, posted. Please mention if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi Sumeet, I am pretty sure *"and 1st window wasn't affected at all"* is cuased by the fact that the second window was minimized. Mind:  ***The script below will do exactly as you describe on the two youngest windows, that is: the two windows that were last created.*** Please make sure you run it on the latest two windows. The offset is something that happens occasionally here, and is the result of a kind of buggy wmctrl i.c.w. your window manager. I am not sure I can fix it. It is not the *command* that is wrong, but it is occasionally executed in a buggy manner.

Comment: yes, i came to know that as well. can you solve the second problem? the *offset*

Comment: @JacobVlijm then it's as close as it can get, I'm really getting used to it when dragging and dropping files from one nautilus window to another one.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably keep working on it. Will update of course if I can fix occasional offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Important note!

The script below will do exactly as you describe ***on the two youngest*** windows, that is: the two windows that were last created.

#### The script, behavior

- The script acts on *dragging* one of the two "newest" windows to one of the two areas on the screen, as shown in the image.

  [image]

  The area is deliberately *not* tight into the corner, to make sure it does not interfere with "normal"window snapping.
- If the window is dragged on to either one of the areas, the script waits 0.15 second to see if the mouse is still in the same position, to make sure not to act if the user was "on his way" to the corner of the screen for normal window snapping.
- Subsequently, the dragged window is snapped into the half of the screen the area is on, the second window is snapped to the opposite side of the screen

  *1. drag the window to the area*

  [image]

  *2. the window snaps, the other one snaps to the opposite site*

  [image]
- finally, as a confirmation, a notification shows during three seconds:

  [image]

  [See the script in action](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyxi4m099pbgetg/fillscreen.avi?dl=0)

#### The script & setup

The setup involves two items:

- the script:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  import sys
  import os
  import subprocess
  import time
  from operator import itemgetter
  from itertools import groupby
  import math

  #--- set your preferences below: padding between windows, margin(s)
  cols = 2; rows = 1; padding = 20; left_margin = 0; top_margin = 30
  #---

  fpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  n_wins = cols*rows


  def get_spot(pos):
      # get the resolution
      scrdata = get("xrandr").split(); resindex = scrdata.index("connected")+2
      res = [int(n) for n in scrdata[resindex].split("+")[0].split("x")]
      # list the corners, could be more elegant no doubt
      corners = [[0, res[1]], [res[0], res[1]]]
      diff = [int(math.sqrt(sum([(c[i]-pos[i])**2 for i, n in enumerate(res)])))\
              for c in corners]
      return diff

  def get(cmd):
      try:
          return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
      except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
          pass

  def get_res():
      xr = get("xrandr").split(); pos = xr.index("current")
      return [int(xr[pos+1]), int(xr[pos+3].replace(",", "") )]

  def get_pos():
      return [int(s.split(":")[1]) for s in get(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).split()[:2]]


  def check_window(w_id):
      w_type = get(["xprop", "-id", w_id])
      if " _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in w_type:
          return True
      else:
          return False

  def confirm():
      val = False
      mouseloc = get_spot(get_pos())
      match = [mouseloc.index(n) for n in mouseloc if 50 < n < 400]
      if match:
          time.sleep(0.15)
          val = True if get_spot(get_pos()) == mouseloc else False
      return val, match

  def arrange_wins(active, side):
      # get resolution
      res = get_res()
      # define (calculate) the area to divide
      area_h = res[0] - left_margin; area_v = res[1] - top_margin
      # create a list of calculated coordinates
      x_coords = [int(left_margin+area_h/cols*n) for n in range(cols)]
      y_coords = [int(top_margin+area_v/rows*n) for n in range(rows)]
      coords = sum([[(cx, cy) for cx in x_coords] for cy in y_coords], [])
      # calculate the corresponding window size, given the padding, margins, columns and rows
      w_size = [str(int(area_h/cols - padding)), str(int(area_v/rows - padding))]
      # find windows of the application, identified by their pid
      active = hex(int(get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])))
      active = active[:2]+(10-len(active))*"0"+active[2:]
      wlist = [w.split()[0] for w in get(["wmctrl", "-l"]).splitlines()]
      w_list = [w for w in wlist if check_window(w) == True][-n_wins:]
      try:
          w_list = w_list[::-1] if w_list.index(active) != side else w_list
      except ValueError:
          pass
      else: 
          print(w_list)
          # remove possibly maximization, move the windows
          for n, w in enumerate(w_list):
              data = (",").join([str(item) for item in coords[n]])+","+(",").join(w_size)
              cmd1 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -b remove,maximized_horz"
              cmd2 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -b remove,maximized_vert"
              cmd3 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -e 0,"+data
              for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
                  subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

  wins1 = []

  while True:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      windata = get(["wmctrl", "-lG"])
      if windata:
          wins2 = [[l[0], l[2]] for l in [
              ln.split() for ln in windata.splitlines()]
                     ]
          # combined window locations old/new, grouped to see if moved
          winlocs = sorted(wins1 + wins2, key = itemgetter(0))
          test = [[item, [item[1] for item in list(occ)]] \
                  for item, occ in groupby(winlocs, itemgetter(0))]
          for item in test:
              # old loc, new loc of window
              locs = item[1]
              # window moves?
              if locs.count(locs[0]) != len(locs):
                  args = confirm()
                  if args[0]:
                      arrange_wins(item[0], args[1][0])
                      subprocess.Popen([
                          "notify-send", "-i", os.path.join(
                              fpath, "left.png"), "Fill screen"
                          ])
                      time.sleep(3)
                      subprocess.Popen(["pkill", "notify-osd"])
          wins1 = wins2
  ```
- an icon to show in the notification

  [image]

***Setup***

1. Install both `xdotool`and `wmctrl`
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `fillscreen.py` in a dedicated folder somewhere.
3. Right- click on the icon above, save it as (exactly) `left.png` ***in one and the same folder as the script***.
4. Now open a terminal, run the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/fillscreen.py
   ```

   Note that this terminal window is one of the two windows the script will snap. Draf the terminal to either one of the areas on the left or right. The two most recent windows should snap.
5. If all works fine, add the script to startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/fillscreen.py"
   ```

#### Note

Due to the fact that the script only acts on window movement, and subsequently all further actions are dependent on the situation, the script is very low on juice. Much lower then I expected it to be when I started working on it.

Comment: everything worked except the last point, it says *text ended before matching quote was found for "* i tried to add quote after  **"sleep 10"** or **"sleep" 10**, it got saved but the script isn't working, maybe i did it wrong. another point is when it does work (by manually) starting it in terminal, their is a strange offset to windows

Comment: Hi @SumeetDeshmukh 1. is a typo, 2. can be tweaked a bit, but applcations/windowmanagers handle windowpositions slightly different. Could you post a screenshot somewhere?