# 4 equally sized windows on Ubuntu with GNOME 3

Tags: 17.10, compiz, gnome-shell, ccsm

I have just updated from 17.04 to 17.10. Using ccsm [from this 2015 discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701945/is-it-possible-to-have-four-equally-sized-windows-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) is not working, contrary to what happened when I updated from previous versions.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

By default GNOME provides only "half-tiling" feature (two windows, one on the left half, the other on the right).

For advanced tiling options you may look for some extensions in [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/), for example:

- [zTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1298/ztile/)
- [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)
- [Tilingnome](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1286/tilingnome/)
- [shellshape](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/294/shellshape/)
- [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)

etc.

Comment: Those are more sophisticated than original Ubuntu/Unity experience, as far as I can tell. Still looking for simple, working out of the box solution…

Comment: Looks like ShellTile and gTile are the two best options in this list: I went with gTile. Works a treat. Thanks!

Comment: None of these appear to support "drag the window to one corner to scale to quarter screen"

Comment: Try gTile with "2x2 0:1 0:1" resize format.