# How can I enable horizontal window tiling on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, window-manager, tiling

I wanted to ask if there was an option in Ubuntu 17.10 to enable horizontal window tiling.

This video shows a good example of what I am looking for:

https://youtu.be/F27zZBwtVmc?t=19

When hovering a window to the top of the screen, the window is maximized. I would like it to instead, fill the top half of the screen. When I hover the window to the bottom the of the screen, nothing happens, I would like to make the window fill the bottom half of the screen. Also corner tiling would be nice as well.

Let me know if this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like compiz. You didn't say though what DE are you running, so I assume Gnome. Check [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/), maybe it has horizontal tiles.

Comment: See if this answer is useful: https://askubuntu.com/a/966907/480481

Comment: Thanks Angel! ShellTile does exactly what I want. The only issue now, is that the default tiling behavior is still there. So what I mean is when I drag a window to the bottom of the screen, ShellTile makes that window fill the bottom half of the screen, which is the exact behavior I wanted. However, when I move the window to the top of the screen, the window still get maximized. Also, when I want to a window to fill the bottom left corner, it will fill the left side side of the screen, which is the default behavior. How can I disable the default tiling behavior, and use ShellTile's instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now have the behavior I want, I can tile my windows left, right, all four corners, top half and bottom half. Here is what I did for anyone who wants to know:

I installed the ShellTile extension for GNOME Shell.

After installing that, I faced another issue. ShellTile was working but it's functionality was being replaced by the default tiling behavior.

[This forum post](https://superuser.com/questions/599561/prevent-gnome-from-expanding-windows) explains how to remove the default tiling behavior, in favor of ShellTile's.

I was told to type:

**`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false`**

But that didn't work, so I ended up going with the second answer and installed dconf-editor by typing:

**`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`**

Here are the instructions for what to do next:

> - You need dconf-editor. Install it per your distribution's recommendations. I'm running Fedora 17 at the moment and this is the command line incantation I used: sudo yum install dconf-editor.
> - Launch dconf-editor. On the left you will see a simple menu with five entries. Click on the plus sign to the left of org. New menu entires will drop down beneath it. Click on the plus sign to the left of gnome. Scroll down, then click on the plus sign to the left of mutter.
> - Click on mutter next to the plus sign to highlight it. Several entries will appear in the large window to the right.
>     If the edge-tiling entry is checked, click it to uncheck it. If it is already unchecked, leave it unchecked.
> - Scroll down the left panel and click on the plus sign to the left of shell.
> - Go to the overrides entry below shell and click on it.
> - Again, you are looking for the edge-tiling entry in the right window. Make sure it is not checked.
> - Close dconf-editor.
>
> Note: This turns off all edge-tiling. The Gnome Shell effect that snaps a window to the left or right side of the screen and opens it to one-half screenwidth will not work after disabling edge-tiling. If you decide to get it back, return to dconf-editor and re-enable it.

That's basically it. I give thanks to [Hi-Angel](https://askubuntu.com/users/266507/hi-angel) and [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) for mentioning ShellTile. I hope this helps someone else who wants the same functionality I wanted.

Thanks again.

Comment: If this answer works for you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. Nothing wrong with accepting your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
then do these step in dconf-editor:

```
 -> open org/gnome/mutter and set edge tiling to ON

 -> open org/gnome/shell/overrides and set edge tiling to ON

 -> open org/gnome/metacity and set edge tiling to ON
```

Hope this for u all too.