# resized window to a quarter of desktop size... ubuntu17.10

Tags: compiz, 17.10, window-manager, resize

I have installed ubuntu 17.10 and cannot put windows in the corner of desktop screen. In 16.04 I guess it was all done by CompizConfig... I installed Gnome extension Put Windows but it does not really resize window to quarter of the screen... Do you have anybody some suggestions how to set it up?

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966905/ubuntu-17-10-4-equally-sized-windows

Comment: thank you I think I will need to get use with one of them, though I really liked that easy keyboard shortcuts window managing in unity :)