# Can't horizontally split the screen with GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gui, window, window-manager

I'm using GNOME 3.28.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.4.

With the keyboard shortcuts "Special" + "Left Arrow", I can move the current window to the left, and resize it to half the screen; with "Right Arrow", the same, but to the right. A vertical split of the screen is created

With "Up Arrow", the window is resized to full screen. I would like instead to move it to the upper half of the screen. In other words, I would like to obtain a horizontal split of the screen, similar to the vertical split which is obtained with "Left" and "Right Arrow".

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Related: [4 equally sized windows on Ubuntu with GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/q/966905/480481)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/579 shows it's a requested feature not yet implemented directly in GNOME3.

However, there's an [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/) for GNOME, [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/), which gets you there, as illustrated in https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/tiling-windows-in-gnome-shell/ with its Manual Tiling option. Switch to an app then manually redraw its tile for its horizontal slice (top or bottom). Switch to another app, and manually redraw its tile.  gTile looks at the grid drawing and scales apps accordingly.

[tilingnome](https://github.com/rliang/gnome-shell-extension-tilingnome/blob/master/README.md) also allows you do do this and also offers horizontal layouts.